# General error: 1114 The table '/var/db/mysql_tmpdir/#sql3cac_5b34d_1' is full - Magento 2.4.2

Tags: mysql, magento2

We are running into an error on a Magento 2.4.2 site where when "is anchor" is set to Yes for a category the page will not load without an error.

We believe it may be something to do with the layered navigation on the site.  It looks like we could increase innodb_data_file_path to fix but don't have this issue on other sites and would like to get to the bottom of what is causing it.

Any ideas appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIxJl.png

Answer (score 0):

the storage of the db engine may be full?
or check your maximum size of temporary tables which could be created by group by or join.

Comment: Thank you, so it is more likely something we need to change on the server than an issue within the code?

Comment: Yup. You gonna go to check the global settings to the temporary tabel of your db engine